# Good practice sharing resources between modules?

Tags: python, module, namespaces, global

I am reorganizing my code and therefore creating new namespaces. I'm changing "static" classes (classes with @staticmethod in each method) for modules. This is the way to go, right?

The problem is that I have doubts on how to share the resources between these modules.

Let's say I had a module from which I was doing all connections to database, and of course all classes/methods were sharing the variable which stored the DB cursor (I'm using SQLite). Now, in different modules, they also have to share the cursor.

[image: Graphical representation of dependences]

So, my ideas:

- Declare the global variable in each module. But globals are evil, eat children and steal our jobs. So I don't know if this is the way to go.

  ```
  '''Sub Module 1'''

  global database_cursor
  ```
- Import the "father" database_module with the original database_cursor and use something like this:

  ```
  '''Sub Module 1'''

  db_cursor = database_module.database_cursor
  ```

This second looks fine in this case, but I think in many cases will lead to recursive imports, which I guess it´s something to avoid.

Comment: I think you may be [overengineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering). If the functions needs a cursor to work on just add a parameter `cursor` to the functions and you are done. The code that calls all the function will create a single local variable containing the cursor and passing it around to all the functions. Also, I'd say a single module for the database management is enough. If you find that you need more organization then you are better using something like `SQLAlchemy`.

Comment: I don't think this is over engineering. It is perfectly legit to share things like database connections to avoid unnecessary reinitialization. I however do think it is wise to look into connection pooling for this. Otherwise you get probably problems with the connection still in use from a previous call.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your second method is the way to go. Python imports are singleton by nature. When a module is imported multiple times it is only executed the first time. Subsequent imports fetch the module object instance from the globals. More on that [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).

shared.py:

```
class Shared:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Init shared")

    def do_stuff(self, from_mod):
        print("Do stuff from {0}. I am instance {1}".format(from_mod, self))

shared = Shared()
```

foo.py

```
import shared

shared.shared.do_stuff("foo")
```

bar.py

```
import foo
import shared

shared.shared.do_stuff("bar")
```

If we execute bar.py we get:

```
>>> Init shared
>>> Do stuff from foo. I am instance <shared.Shared instance at 0x10046df38>
>>> Do stuff from bar. I am instance <shared.Shared instance at 0x10046df38>
```

So in your case you can reference `database_module` from anywhere you want and it gets initialized only once, therefore effectively sharing your connection.

Comment: If you execute foo.py and bar.py separately in a sequence, does that mean the __init__ method executes twice ? Im trying to understand if the singleton behavior applies when same module is imported multiple within a module or across modules?

Comment: Note that that in the python docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import-stmt this process is not written up too explicitly; the key statement is "initializing it if necessary", where "if necessary" is to be interpreted as "has not been previously initialized".