# Using the same SQLite3 connection over multiple Python modules

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, python-telegram-bot

I'm coding a Telegram Bot in Python3, using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). Currently, all the code is placed in a single file (with >1k lines), and the structure is like:

```
    import ...
    a lot of bot's functions called by python-telegram-bot
    database connection (SQLite3 using SQLAlchemy)
    message's handlers
    bot.polling()
```

I want to split this monolithic file in multiple python's files, by grouping functions that have a similar purpose. But, i don't know how to handle the database connection: in the main file I've a `session` "global" variable created with sqlalchemy and used by all the other functions because it's in the same scope. How to proper manage this over multiple files? What's the best way?

Comment: You'll have multiple modules that want visibility to that global variable. So put that variable in a modue that doesn't do any project imports. Now the other modules can import that module without worry of circular dependencies and see that same variable. Alternately, all of your modularized functions could include the connection object as a parameter.

Comment: Related: CodeReview [Sharing a database connection with multiple modules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64671/sharing-a-database-connection-with-multiple-modules). similar (closed as OT) [Good practice sharing resources between modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642654/good-practice-sharing-resources-between-modules).

Comment: @tdelaney - after reading your comment I'm not sure my answer is correct. Care to comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create database connection in another file and assign to some variable.

After that import and use it wherever you need to get/modify data in database.

**P.S.** Don't do any `app` imports in that file to avoid circular dependency.

**P.P.S.** [Link provided by @wwii](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64675) should help with examples